# SQL Server 2016 shows (Hypervisor) in the version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a server that is acting odd; the memory usage keeps creeping up and some reports just spontaneously quit working, and some database jobs sometimes fail.  I have another backup server that runs the same configuration (runs Windows Server 2016 with the same patches, etc.), and that server runs fine, the memory usage stays around 30gb, and never misses a beat.  The 2 servers are mirrored with each other.

To isolate the issue, I upgraded both the databases to the latest CU, and noticed that on the sqirrly server, it has (Hypervisor) in the version name:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU6) (KB4037354) - 13.0.4457.0 (X64)   
Nov 8 2017 17:32:23   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation   
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393:) (Hypervisor)
```

The good server has everything but that and they are both 'bare metal' servers with no virtualization.  Could this be an issue?  How do I get the (Hypervisor) out of the version?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [SQL Server, @@VERSION, and Hyper-V](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2016/03/07/sql-server-version-and-hyper-v.aspx) :

> The addition of (HYPERVISOR) to the output indicates only whether or not Hyper-V is currently enabled on the machine. **It is not intended to indicate if SQL Server is running inside a Hyper-V virtual machine.**
>
> Disable Hyper-V on the machine and the text goes away.

Personally I would leave it "as-is".